# Is there a way to pass a configuration file file from a client app to a library project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I am building a library project that uses a configuration file to generate custom resources. I have a gradle plugin that does this during the build phase. Unless there is another solution I would like to store these resources inside the library's build folder so they can be accessed without having to declare placeholder values. The problem is that the configuration file needs to be supplied by the client app. But of course, if I apply the plugin to my library I do not have access to the client app's directories where the file is stored. And if I apply it to the client app I cannot store the generated resources in the library's build folder. Is there a way to pass this between the two projects? Or if my approach just completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently the only way would be to use customs style attributes. I found a description here: https://blog.danlew.net/2011/03/03/custom_styles_in_android_libraries/

The only problem is that this solution would force the client app to depend on the theme declared in the library. This won't work for my use-case. Instead I decided it'd be simpler to use placeholders. I therefore declared all my colors, dimensions and styles as null objects and then these are overridden once the client app is built.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to implement configuration in client app. 
1. Create an interface in lib project 
2. Implement that interface in client app. 
3. Do configurable things in client app implemented interface. 
4. Call interface method in lib project(where you need actual configuration)